# Reordering tags

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

[This might be the most arcane question I've ever asked.] I recently asked a question and, of course, provided a collection of tags. When the question was posted, the tags were not listed in the order I originally wrote them. Why? Is it just that the tags are presented in alphabetic order. That'd be boring; I'm hoping for something subtler.

Aha. A self-referential question. The same thing happened just now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags are [sorted (decreasingly) by the number of questions that have been asked with them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50794/possible-bug-in-retagging/50819#50819). This happens when a question is edited (even if you don't edit the tags, they may be reordered if their popularity has changed).

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping for something more exotic.